# Improper output while calling ajax request and appending output

Tags: python, ajax, web2py

Ajax output is

```
\u001b[1mGetting NS records for yahoo.com\u001b[0m\n\n\n\nIp Address\tServer Name\n\n----------\t-----------\n\n68.180.131.16\tns1.yahoo.com\n\n98.138.11.157\tns4.yahoo.com\n\n203.84.221.53\tns3.yahoo.com\n\n68.142.255.16\tns2.yahoo.com\n\n119.160.247.124\tns5.yahoo.com\n\n202.43.223.170\tns6.yahoo.com\n\n\n\nZone Transfer not enabled\n\n
```

When I append into html it looks like

```
[1mGetting NS records for yahoo.com[0m Ip Address   Server Name ----------  ----------- 68.180.131.16   ns1.yahoo.com 98.138.11.157 ns4.yahoo.com 203.84.221.53 ns3.yahoo.com 68.142.255.16 ns2.yahoo.com 119.160.247.124   ns5.yahoo.com 202.43.223.170    ns6.yahoo.com Zone Transfer not enabled
```

"\t" "\n" doesnt seem to be working.

Please help.

Comment: You need to form your ajax output into HTML/XML first. It shouldn't work as is.

Answer (score 1):

HTML does not render tabs and line breaks. For a line break in HTML, use `<br>`. There are no tabs in HTML, but if you just want to insert some spaces, you can use `&nbsp;` for each blank space (of course, you can always insert a single space, but multiple spaces will get collapsed unless you explicitly use `&nbsp;`).

Another option is to wrap your text in a `<pre></pre>` element to display the text exactly as you have it formatted in the HTML source (you may need to play with the CSS if you don't like the default formatting of `<pre>` content). web2py also includes a [`CODE()`](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/05/the-views#CODE) helper, which uses `<pre>` but also enables line numbers and syntax highlighting.

Comment: perfect! :) thank you so much! I am really stupid that I forgot about <pre> tag.